# Vite: Material-ui theme context not shared into libraries

Tags: material-ui, vite

I am providing MUI theme like this in root:

```
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUTCUtils}>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <>
                        <CssBaseline />
                        <App />
                    </>
                </Router>
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
```

Then somewhere in App, I render a component that is accessing theme context from another node package like this:

```js
    const variantColors = new Map<ToastVariant, string >([
        [ToastVariant.Common, theme.palette.primary.main],
        [ToastVariant.Error, theme.palette.common.Error.fill],
        [ToastVariant.Info, theme.palette.common.Warning.fill],
        [ToastVariant.Success, theme.palette.common.Success.fill],
    ])
```

and it throws the following error:

```js
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fill')
```

Error suggests that theme is not initialized as was provided in context.

With Webpack this worked.

Package is compiled into ESM format and imported

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to delete yarn.lock and reinstall everything. Probably messed up some material-ui dependencies or something like that.